# (Python2) Combining pandas dataframe of mulilayer columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I want to add values of dataframe of which format is same.
for exmaple

```
>>> my_dataframe1

         class1 score
subject  1    2    3
student
0        1    2    5
1        2    3    9
2        8    7    2
3        3    4    7
4        6    7    7

>>> my_dataframe2

         class2 score
subject  1    2    3
student
0        4    2    2
1        4    4    14
2        8    7    7
3        1    2    NaN
4        NaN  2    3
```

as you can see, the two dataframes have multi-layer columns that the main column is 'class score' and the sub columns is 'subject'.
what i want to do is that get summed dataframe which can be showed like this

```
            score
subject  1    2    3
student
0        5    4    7
1        2    1    5
2        16   14   9
3        4    6    7
4        6    9    10
```

Actually, i could get this dataframe by

```
for i in my_dataframe1['class1 score'].index:
    my_dataframe1['class1 score'].loc[i,:] = my_dataframe1['class1 score'].loc[i,:].add(my_dataframe2['class2 score'].loc[i,:], fill_value = 0)
```

but, when dimensions increases, it takes tremendous time to get result dataframe, and i do think it isn't good way to solve problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `values` from the second dataframe, it will ignore the indexing

```
# you don't need `astype(int)`.
my_dataframe1.add(my_dataframe2.values, fill_value=0).astype(int)

        class1 score        
subject            1   2   3
student                     
0                  5   4   7
1                  6   7  23
2                 16  14   9
3                  4   6   7
4                  6   9  10
```

---

**Setup**

```
my_dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 5],
    [2, 3, 9],
    [8, 7, 2],
    [3, 4, 7],
    [6, 7, 7]
], pd.RangeIndex(5, name='student'), pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['class1 score'], [1, 2, 3]], names=[None, 'subject']))

my_dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [4, 2, 2],
    [4, 4, 14],
    [8, 7, 7],
    [1, 2, np.nan],
    [np.nan, 2, 3]
], pd.RangeIndex(5, name='student'), pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['class2 score'], [1, 2, 3]], names=[None, 'subject']))
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df_out = df['class1 score'].add(df2['class2 score'],fill_value=0).add_prefix('scores_')

df_out.columns = df_out.columns.str.split('_',expand=True)

df_out
```

Output:

```
        scores          
             1   2     3
student                 
0          5.0   4   7.0
1          6.0   7  23.0
2         16.0  14   9.0
3          4.0   6   7.0
4          6.0   9  10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is keep the data in the same dataframe. You could concatenate the two you have already:

```
big_df = pd.concat([my_dataframe1, my_dataframe2], axis=1)
```

Then sum over the larger dataframe, specifying `level`:

```
big_df.sum(axis=1, level='subject')
```